# How do you create a grade object with a non-integer max_points? Currently the max_points are being rounded to the nearest integer

Tags: desire2learn, valence

Our system has some questions that are worth a non-integer grade value (say 1.5). In trying to sync our grading data with d2l, creating a grade object with a non-integer max_points seems to result in a grade object with a max_points value that’s been rounded to the nearest integer (in our case of 1.5, the grade object is now out of 2).

I’ve observed that from within d2l, I can set a grade’s max_points to a non-integer value, so I’m lead to believe that this issue is either a result of calling the api incorrectly, or a result of some rounding bug on the api layer.

We’re creating this grade object with a POST to the following end-point
/d2l/api/le/1.0/(orgUnitId)/grades/

with the following grade data:
{'IsBonus': False, 'CanExceedMaxPoints': False, 'Name': u'Question', 'ExcludeFromFinalGradeCalculation': False, 'GradeSchemeId': None, 'CategoryId': 8856, 'MaxPoints': 1.5, 'GradeType': 'Numeric', 'ShortName': '', 'Description': {'Content': u'367', 'Type': 'Text'}}

It’s worth noting that the object returned in the response to that POST request has the correct max_points value (not rounded).

Is there something else we should be passing int the POST request so that the max_points is not rounded?

Comment: I notice that you're using the 1.0 version of this route, which is currently obsolete. Can you tell me what version of the D2L LE you're using so that we can determine the latest version of the route that you can use? For example with D2L LE version 10.3 you can use the 1.4 version of this route. I want to be sure if we discover a defect in the route, that it hasn't already been fixed in a supported version of the API.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a defect, which I've confirmed using the 1.4 version of this route. Please have your Approved Support Contact open an incident with D2L Support to report this defect.